# Scrollbar in html

Tags: html, css, adminlte

Can someone help me to fix this?

I have html page using template from `admin-LTE` and there's 2 'scrollbar-y' in my page. Can I remove the scrollbar from **admin-LTE**?, because I tried, it can remove 1 scrollbar but I cant scroll to my footer page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, I have used this in the past to make the scrollbar disappear I don't know if it will get rid of both of them though.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow:hidden;` to css of the element that you want to remove scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

You can hide scroll by using the following `CSS` or `JS` approach:

CSS way:

```
#element-id{
  overflow-y:hidden
}
```

Or using JS way:

```
document.getElementById("your-id").style.overflowY="hidden"
```

Comment: Do you know using `JS` approach can lead to `reflow` or `layout` to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying overflow css on the element on which the scroll is happening, hopefully it will be resolved

```
overflow:hidden;
```